# wrapping code that runs in Rails environment into a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have this code and it works perfectly

```
    require "date"
        @past = []
        @future = []

    @artist = Artist.find(2)

    def sort_by_date(artist)
        artist.events.each do |event|
            if event.date < DateTime.now
                @past << event.id
            else
                @future << event.id
            end
        end
    end

    def event_title(arr)
        arr.each do |event_id|
            e = Event.find(event_id)
            artist_names = []

            e.artists.each do |artist|
                unless artist.name == @artist.name
                    artist_names << artist.name
                end
            end

            puts "#{e.name} with #{artist_names.join(", ")} at #{(Venue.find(e.venue_id)).name}"
        end
    end

  sort_by_date(@artist)
  puts "Upcoming Events: "
  event_title(@future)
  puts "Past Events: "
  event_title(@past)
```

I want to run wrap this operation into a module, but I'm having trouble understanding how to pass `artist_id` to it properly. With this command `rails runner app/modules/artist_event_sort.rb`, I'm getting this error: ``': undefined method `sort_by_date' for SortedArtistEvents:Module (NoMethodError)`. The two methods `sort_by_date` and `event_title` worked as they should before I tried wrapping this whole operation up into a module, so that's where I know I've missed something.

```
module SortedArtistEvents
    require "date"
    attr_accessor :artist_id
    def initialize(artist_id)
        @past = []
        @future = []
        @artist = Artist.find(artist_id)
    end


    def sort_by_date(artist)
        artist.events.each do |event|
            if event.date < DateTime.now
                @past << event.id
            else
                @future << event.id
            end
        end
    end

    def event_title(arr)
        arr.each do |event_id|
            e = Event.find(event_id)
            artist_names = []

            e.artists.each do |artist|
                unless artist.name == @artist.name
                    artist_names << artist.name
                end
            end

            puts "#{e.name} with #{artist_names.join(", ")} at #{(Venue.find(e.venue_id)).name}"

        end
    end

  sort_by_date(@artist)
  puts "Upcoming Events: "
  self.event_title(@future)
  puts "Past Events: "
  event_title(@past)
end

class LetsSort
  include SortedArtistEvents
end
test_artist_sort = LetsSort.new(2)
```

Comment: you are including: ArtistEventSort but the module is called: SortedArtistEvents.

Comment: oh man, ok I fixed that. still the same error, though.

Comment: how are you initialising your module from the LetsSort class?

Comment: I just included it in the `LetsSort` class, which is just a dummy class to test my module in action. Also, as user nikkypx suggested, I changed the method to `self.sort_by_date`, which led to this error `undefined method 'events'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple things wrong here. You are trying to initialize a module, you can only initialize a class, e.g. `class SortedArtistEvents`.

If you have this:

```
module Foo
  def bar; end
end
```

`bar` is only accessible by including or extending a module or class with `Foo`. With your error `undefined method sort_by_date' for SortedArtistEvents:Module` you would have to do

```
module SortedArtistsEvents
  def self.sort_by_date; end
end
```

to get behavior like `SortedArtistsEvents.sort_by_date`

Comment: I have created a class that initialized my module, it's towards the end of my code. When including a module, do all of its methods have to have `self` in order to use them?

Comment: no they don't, it would probably be faster to google, see here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm

Comment: ok so, adding keyword `sort` to that method, I get the `undefined method 'events'` that is inside of it. that's another that's wrong here - `@artist` variable does not get declared properly.